# how to validate request using css class

Tags: javascript, jquery

javascript.js

```
function activeuser(userId) {
  $.post("/admin/activate_user", {
      userid: userId
  }, function (response) {
  });
}
```

user.php

```
 <span id="enable<?=$user->id; ?>" class="cb-enable <?=$active_class;?>" onclick="return activeuser(<?= $user->id ?>);"><span>Active</span></span>
   <span id="disenable<?=$user->id; ?>" class="cb-disable <?=$deactive_class;?>" onclick="return deactiveuser(<?= $user->id ?>);"><span>De-active</span></span>
```

On click of the span i am sending an ajax request and doing some action.I need to validate like this,in my span if the class is `cb-enable selected` if i press that button,it should not send the ajax request.Is it possible to validate with the css class before ajax post.

Please see my ajax function in javascript.js

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.hasClass()` to accomplish your task at this context

Try,

```
if($('#thatSpan').hasClass('cb-enable') && $('#thatSpan').hasClass('selected'))
{
  //your code goes here.
}
```

Or you can use `.is()` also

```
if($('#thatSpan').is('.cb-enable.selected'))
{
  //your code goes here.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tyr this, you can check for the availability of class using hasClass() method of jquery.

```
function activeuser(userId){
    if(! ($(this).hasClass('cb-enable') && $(this).hasClass('selected')) ){
        $.post("/admin/activate_user", 
            {       
            userid: userId
            }, 
            function(response){
                if(response == "active"){
                    $('#enable'+userId).addClass('selected');
                    $('#disenable'+userId).removeClass('selected');
                    $('#disenable'+userId).addClass('pointer');
                    $('#enable'+userId).removeClass('pointer');
            }
         }); 
    }
}
```